# If $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $X$, then $\sigma(\mathcal{A}) = \mathcal{A}$

Tags: measure-theory

I would like to prove:

> If $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $X$, then $\sigma(\mathcal{A}) = \mathcal{A}$.

My attempt:

Each $\sigma$-algebra in the intersection in the definition of $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ contains $\mathcal{A}$, so we have $\mathcal{A} \subset \sigma(\mathcal{A})$.

For the other direction, I'm a bit stuck. Let's consider $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$. We know that it is the intersection of all $\sigma$-algebras containing $\mathcal{A}$. Now it would seem that since $\mathcal{A}$ is the "smallest" such $\sigma$-algebra that we've shown containment and we're done, but I'm not sure how to write this out formally.

Comment: Use the minamility of $\sigma(\mathcal A)$ along with $\mathcal A\subset \mathcal A$. In other words $\sigma(\mathcal A)$ is contained in every $\sigma$-algebra which contains $\mathcal A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have difficulties in writing it formally, because you are not used writing trivial things formally.

By definition, $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ is the intersection of the set $\mathcal{F}$ all $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $X$ containing $\mathcal{A}$. But if $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, then $\mathcal{A}\in \mathcal{F}$. It follows that $\sigma(\mathcal{A})=\bigcap\mathcal{F}\subseteq\mathcal{A}$.